# Export png thumbnail from Zingchart graph not working for CSV data

Tags: javascript, plot, charts, phantomjs, zingchart

I would like to generate `.png` thumbnails of graphs made with Zingchart. This is to generate an *index* of the multiple graphs I create and I want to do it without opening the actual graph in a browser.

I found this piece of documentation:

- [Server Side and PhantomJS Chart Export](https://www.zingchart.com/docs/developers/phantomjs-chart-export/)

And I think this is what I want.

So I tried with

```
  phantomjs /home/eballes/Work/backup/zingchart_test/zingchart_2.3.2_phantomjs/zingchart-phantomjs.min.js -width=800 -height=600 -dataurl=/home/eballes/Work/t/test_output/html/example.html -filename=out.png
```

However, the command just hangs there producing no output and consuming no CPU. If I execute with `strace` what I see is an infinite loop of polling / timeout:

```
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 2, 31) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 2, 1) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 2, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 2, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 2, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 2, 34) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 2, 31) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 2, 1) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 2, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
```

In the command line the `-dataurl` parameter is supposed to be a JSON file. The content of `example.html` is the following:

```
    {
      "globals":{
          "font-family":"Arial"
      },  
      "legend":{
          "layout":"4x",
          "adjust-layout":true,
          "align":"center",
          "background-color":"none",
          "shadow":0,
          "border-width":0,
          "vertical-align":"bottom",
      },  
      "type": "line",
      "utc":true, 
      "csv": {
        "url": "csv/data.csv",
        "separator": "|",
        "vertical-labels": true,
        "horizontalLabels": true
      },  
      "plot":{
          "line-width":2,
          "active-area":true,
          "shadow":0,
          "exact":false,
          "marker":{
              "size":4
          },
          "hover-marker":{
              "size":3
          },
          "preview":true,
          "spline":false,
          "maxNodes":100,
          "maxTrackers":2000,
          "marker": {
              "rules": [
                {
                    "rule": '%i%10 > 0',
                    "visible": false,
                }
              ],
          },
      },
      "plotarea":{
          "adjust-layout":1,
          "width":"100%",
          "height":200,
          "position":"0% 0%",
          "margin-top":60,
          "margin-right":60,
          "margin-left":70,
          "margin-bottom":105
      },
      "preview":{
          "visible":true,
          "height":40,
          "position":"0 370",
          "margin-top":10,
          "margin-bottom":15
      },
      "scale-x":{
          "format":"%v",
          "zooming":true,
          "step":"1hour",
          "max-items":24,
          "label":{
              "margin-top":100
          },
          "tick":{
              "line-color":"black",
              "line-width":"2px",
              "size":8,
          },
          "item":{
            "font-size":10
          },
          "transform":{
            "type":"date",
            "all":"%d/%M/%Y\n%H:%i:%s",
          }
      },
      "scale-y":{
          "zooming":true,
          "decimals":2,
          "label":{
            "text": "Label",
          },
      },
      "tooltip":{
        "shadow":0,
        "font-color":"#000",
        "text":"%t - %k<br><br>%v<br>Hz",
        "border-radius":"5px",
        "sticky":true,
        "timeout":500,
        "decimals":6
      }
    }
```

If the JSON has the data directly in it, it works fine and generates the `.png` file. However, with a CSV file it doesn't seem to work and in the `strace` I don't see any attempt on opening the `csv` file.

I updated to `zingchart_2.4.0_phantomjs` with the same results.

What am I missing? Is there a better way to generate the `.png` thumbnails from a CSV file?

Comment: For debugging this issue, what version of phantom are you using?

Comment: @nardecky I will confirm tomorrow since I don't have the work laptop with me, but I use the phantomjs available from [Debian stretch repository](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/phantomjs) which according to the link is version 2.1.1 +dfsg-2 amd64. I will give it a try with the out-of-the-box binary from the official site just in case.

Comment: @nardecky Yes, it is phantomjs version 2.1.1. I've tried with the binary from the official site and the result is the same.

Comment: @nardecky I've done some editing of the post... I've just discover the problem only occurs when there's a CSV linked (as in my example). In other graphs where I directly have the data in the JSON it works. However on the `strace` I can't see any attempt from zingchart at opening the CSV file.....

Comment: My initial curiosity was leaning towards issues with the newer phantom build. Thank you for clarifying the build number and clearing up my concerns. The phantom code does not support a CSV file upload. You could write your own phantom service, but this would be a bit of work.